# Update Records In Django Rest

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am following one Django Video Tutorials and there for updating any record in Model he created one view as :

```
Class UserProfileUpdateDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
   model = UserProfile
```

By above he can fetch any record in Mymodel and update that 
e.g., let say by this url ->  /api/UserProfile/1/

But When I use the same at my end I am getting this error **`UserProfileUpdateDetail should either include a queryset attribute, or override the get_queryset() method.`**

I think it may because of Django Rest Version ?

So If I update my code according to Rest Docs  :

```
class UserProfileUpdateDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

Then I can fetch any record as `e.g., ->  /api/UserProfile/1/`

But when I try to update this this single record not gets updated. LEt say I update the first_name but it says username already exist (But It should update the same record which I have fetched but i think its creating new record).

My Complete Record :

Models.py :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField('Subjects')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Serializer.py

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    # subject = SubjectSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
                'user',
                'subject',
                'phone',
                'address',
            )
```

Views.py

```
class UserProfileUpdateDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

Urls.py

```
 url(r'^api/user/profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', UserProfileUpdateDetail.as_view(), name="user-profile-update"),
```

Comment: Isn't this issue a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33413907/updates-records-related-with-foreign-key-in-django-rest/33416672#33416672 ?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of remarks:

- the way your profile serializer is laid down, it has a nested object there: the user. DRF doesn't support nested serializers out-of-the-box, you have to overwrite the create/update methods on your serializer to specify how you wan them to be handled; further reading here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations.
- I would recommend to instrument the user route and the user serializer to include the profile serializer instead of serializing the profile and then the user from there.
- If you can live with it, have a separate route for profile and user; in some designs this works well, because you will need to alter the profile more often than the user definition. Also, for password reset you will have a separate route, for instance.